# Create array of regex match(multiline)

Tags: java, regex

I want to create array of regex match string from the text bellow.

```
.title1
this is a content of title1.
this is also a content of title1.
..title2
this is a content of title2
this is also a content of title2
```

and desired array is below

```
array[0] = ".title1
this is a content of title1.
this is also a content of title1."

array[1] = "..title2
this is a content of title2
this is also a content of title2"
```

and bellow is my code.

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\.[\w|\W]+^\.", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(textAbove);

if(m.matches()){
  m.reset();
  while(m.find()){
    array.add(m.group());
  }
}
```

But with this code, array[0] contains from ".title1" to "." before ".title2", and couldn't get array[1] since m.find() doesn't match, and when I use `^\.[\w|\W]+` instead of regex pattern above, array[0] contains everything.
How can I acheive this array?
I don't stick to regex, any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close - try this regex instead:

```
^\..*?(?=(^\.|\Z))
```

In java, this would be"

```
"^\\..*?(?=(^\\.|\\Z))" // escaping the backslashes for java String.
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I tested your regex with RegexPlanet( http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html ), but it didn't match at all... what

Comment: Sorry, It matched, but array[0] contains everything. what happened? :(

Comment: oops - i made it a greedy match. I have edited it to include the `?` - making it non-greedy. Try it now