# python regex to find multiline C comment spanning multiple lines

Tags: python, ply

I m trying to get a regex which will work on multi-line C comments. Managed to make it work for /* comments here */ but does not work if the comment goes to the next line. How do I make a regex which spans over multiple lines?

Using this as my input:

/* this comment
must be recognized */

The problem I get is "must, be and recognized" is matched as ID's and */ as illegal characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ply.lex as lex
tokens = ['ID', 'COMMENT']

t_ID   = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'

def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'(?s)/\*(.*?).?(\*/)'
    #r'(?s)/\*(.*?).?(\*/)' does not work either.
    return t

# Error handling rule
def t_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lex.lex()   #Build the lexer

lex.input('/* this comment\r\n must be recognised */\r\n')
while True:
    tok = lex.token()
    if not tok:break
    if tok.type == 'COMMENT':
        print tok.type
```

I tried quite a few: [Create array of regex match(multiline)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774571/create-array-of-regex-matchmultiline?rq=1) and [How to handle multiple rules for one token with PLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669353/how-to-handle-multiple-rules-for-one-token-with-ply) and few other things available at http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html

Comment: Oops! I just realized that you _are_ supplying the DOTALL flag via the alternate `(?s)` syntax. OTOH, your `t_COMMENT(t)` function looks odd. You aren't assigning that regex to anything, and the return statement isn't indented properly.

Comment: Hi @Thapelo.  Welcome to stack overflow.  To help you with this, we probably need a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) As it is, the code you've posted won't run and it's not obvious at the moment what `t_COMMENT` is doing or how you call it.  If you can edit in some more context, I'm sure someone will be along who can help.

Comment: You might find this example useful - it's a full C parser implemented in python, using PLY https://github.com/eliben/pycparser

Comment: Thanks guys for feedback, from ply [docs](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn21) this regex`r'(/\*(.|\n)*?\*/)|(//.*)'`worked for me. There was something wrong with the way I was reading tokens from file.

Answer (score 1):

I use this regex when I want to find multi line comments in C:

If I want to include the '/* */' chars:

```
\/\*(\*(?!\/)|[^*])*\*\/
```

If I don't want to include it:

```
(?<=\*)[\n]*.*[\n]*.*[\n]*[\n]*?[\n]*(?=\*)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, in the regex used by the PLY lexer, the dot `.` does not math a new line `\n`. 
So if you really want to math any character, use `(.|\n)` instead of `.`

(I had the same problem, and your comment on your own question helped me so I just create an answer for the newcomers)

Answer (score -1):

```
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'(?s)/\*.*?\*/'
    return t
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13014995/10528413):

- `(?s)` is a modifier that makes `.` also match new line feeds
- `.*?` is the non-greedy version of `.*`. It that matches the shortest possible sequence of characters (before a `\*/` that comes next)